# DMS partioning tuning in S3 target

Tags: dms

I'm pushing data from a RDS MySQL to S3. My S3 target endpoint have this settings:

```
{
  "CsvRowDelimiter": "\\n",
  "CsvDelimiter": ",",
  "AddColumnName": true,
  "CompressionType": "NONE",
  "EnableStatistics": true,
  "DatePartitionEnabled": true,
  "DatePartitionSequence": "YYYYMMDD",
  "DatePartitionDelimiter": "SLASH",
  "EncryptionMode": "SSE_KMS",
  "ServerSideEncryptionKmsKeyId": "XXXXX",
  "TimestampColumnName":"TIMESTAMP",
  "IncludeOpForFullLoad": true,
  "CdcInsertsOnly": false
}
```

At the end my folder structure is looking like this:

```
-/
--/my_table_name
---LOAD00000001.csv
---/2023
----/01
-----/09
------20230109-165206632.csv
```

I have two questions regarding settings without finding the answer:

- Can we setup some prefix on the date folders? I want to follow Hive naming convention (.eg. /year=2023/month=01/day=09/)
- Is this possible to have the initial load csv file not located at the root, but inside the date folders structure?

Comment: Did you found a way for second question?

Comment: @mmsilviu No i was done like this by design